# $T_1^{n+1}-T_2^{n}$ is prime for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field. Does anyone have an idea how to show that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$T_1^{n+1}-T_2^{n}\in\mathbb{K}[T_1,T_2]$$ is prime?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is prime (even irreducible) since $gcd(n+1,n)=1$, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the principal ideal generated by $T_1^{n+1} - T_2^n$ and show that this is a prime ideal by looking at the quotient $k[T_1,T_2]/(T_1^{n+1} - T_2^n)$. Can you maybe find an integral domain that is isomorphic to $k[T_1,T_2]/(T_1^{n+1} - T_2^n)$?